# Prove or disprove that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

\begin{equation}
  f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
     e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}, & \text{if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
I found out its partial derivatives and showed that they are continuous at $(0,0)$. But is it sufficient? or is there any other way.

Function is obviously continuous at $(0,0)$.

Please help me with the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, that's sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

Use the following:

$x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta $

$h(r) =\begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}} & r\neq 0 \\0 &r=0\end{cases}$

$h\in C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}) $

Comment: Nice way! But here too, we need to find partial derivatives right?

Comment: The function $h$  depends only on $r$.The smoothness of $h$ is known from calculus.